# Incomprehensible expression in Stack ADT implementation

Tags: c, stack

There is a stack ADT implementation below. In this implemantation, programmer has used linked list.

```
struct Node {
    char *elem;
    struct Node *next;
};

static struct Node *new_node(void *elem, int elem_size)
{
    struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    n->elem = malloc(elem_size);
    memcpy(n->elem, elem, elem_size);
    n->next = NULL;

    retrun n;
}

struct Stack {
    int elem_size;
    int n_elems;
    struct Node *top;
}
```

I got it, except the code block as shown below.

```
void stack_push(struct Stack *s, void *elem)
{
    struct Node *n = new_node(elem, s->elem_size);
    n->next = s->top;
    s->top = n;

    s->n_elems++;
}
```

I did not understand that

```
n->next = s->top;
s->top = n;
```

Would anyone like to help me to understand this statements. I will appreciate.

Comment: `n->next` is set to point to what was previously on top of the stack; then `s->top` is set to point to the newly inserted element.

Comment: *headPtr -> A -> B -> C -> NULL, for stack ADT, a new node should add before A because of LIFO?

Comment: given the statement: ' retrun n;' it is obvious this is not a true copy of the code.  Suggest performing a simple copy/paste

Comment: the 'problem' code is simply inserting the new node at the beginning of the linked list.   BTW: the returned value from malloc should always be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push operation adds a new item to the top of the stack. In this implementation, the top of the stack is `s->top`. The second item on the stack is `s->top->next`, the third is `s->top->next->next`, and so on.

I think it is easier to think of

```
n->next = s->top;
s->top = n;
```

as

```
s->top = n;
n->next = s->top;
```

The first statement is making the new node `n` the top of the stack. But the second item of the stack is `NULL` while it should be the old top of the stack. The second statement fixes this, making the old top of the stack the second item of the stack.

Comment: The process goes like that for adding new node i think : A->D->B->NULL if i want to add 'E' to stack, it becomes A->D->B->E->NULL. Am I right ? @neil

Comment: If you *push* `E` it will become `E->A->D->B->NULL`. You need to read up on the [stack data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). What you have described is the behavior you would see in a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try my Paint skillz:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

`NULL` indicates that the node points to nothing, i.e., it is the last node inserted.
Note that `next` points to the next *node*, not to that node's `next`, I just had no better way of showing this here.